# A good gem for filtering and searching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to make a website where every registered users can create posts (a post has_many tags for filtering) representing a product, and anybody can see the posts, can search for a specific word (in the post name, or post tags) and can apply filters (post tags).

I repeat that any registered user can post, not only admins.

What gem could I use?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are dozens of gems/engines etc to help you do this, you can see some of them at:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search

Thinking Sphinx does full-text search, but it sounds like it might be overkill for what you're interested in.

A good tutorial that explores various options and might help get you started is at:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast